# drop frequency column after running value_counts on groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is what my output looks like. Is there a way to get rid of frequency for all rows?

Inputs:

```
by_city = city_df.groupby("city")
total_driver_city = by_city["driver_count"].value_counts()
total_driver_city
```

Outputs:

```
city                  driver_count
Amandaburgh           12              1.0
Barajasview           26              1.0
Barronchester         11              1.0
Bethanyland           22              1.0
Bradshawfurt          7               1.0
Brandonfort           10              1.0
Carriemouth           52              1.0
Christopherfurt       41              1.0
Colemanland           23              1.0
Davidfurt             23              1.0
Deanville             49              1.0
East Aaronbury        7               1.0
East Danielview       22              1.0
East Kaylahaven       65              1.0
```

Comment: Do you want remove last column with `1` ?

Comment: yup. I edited to show my input code.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `iloc`:

```
df = total_driver_city.reset_index().iloc[:,:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need convert `MultiIndex Series` (but if all values are `1` get same columns like `city_df`):

```
df = total_driver_city.reset_index(name='tmp').drop('tmp', axis=1)
print (df)
               city  driver_count
0       Amandaburgh            12
1       Barajasview            26
2     Barronchester            11
3       Bethanyland            22
4      Bradshawfurt             7
5       Brandonfort            10
6       Carriemouth            52
7   Christopherfurt            41
8       Colemanland            23
9         Davidfurt            23
10        Deanville            49
11   East Aaronbury             7
12  East Danielview            22
13  East Kaylahaven            65
```

---

```
df = total_driver_city.index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
               city  driver_count
0       Amandaburgh            12
1       Barajasview            26
2     Barronchester            11
3       Bethanyland            22
4      Bradshawfurt             7
5       Brandonfort            10
6       Carriemouth            52
7   Christopherfurt            41
8       Colemanland            23
9         Davidfurt            23
10        Deanville            49
11   East Aaronbury             7
12  East Danielview            22
13  East Kaylahaven            65
```

Comment: first code works however it is converting it back to dataframe which I don't want. Second code deletes my driver_count column.

Comment: @HaneulKim - What is expected output?

Comment: @Frenchy - Hmmm, ya, if I have time I try answer this tags questions.